# [__NSCFNumber countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nspredicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate 
                             predicateWithFormat:@"todo_category_id IN %@" 
                                   argumentArray:array];
```

`todo_category_id` is an `NSNumber`-type attribute.
`array` contains only 3 elements that are also `NSNumber`-type objects.

I want to fetch categories from Core Data based on these IDs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is wrong because you are using the wrong method. Change to:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todo_category_id IN %@", array];
```

because the whole array should be the format parameter, not just the first item in the array.